# Is it better to say "research under Prof. Aho" or "research under supervision of Prof. Aho"?

Tags: word-usage

When a professor advises and supervises a PhD or MS student to complete their research, is it advisable say?

> The student is conducting his study under Prof. X.

Or

> The student is conducting his study under supervision of Prof. X

I have heard similar usages of *under* as in "Under Obama, this country ...", etc.

Comment: If you and the prof are of opposite genders it's probably best to avoid "under" (without adding "the supervision of").

Comment: Avoid both? what should I say then?

Comment: "under the supervision of" is fine.  It's just that the plain "under" can draw a few distracting snickers, depending on the circumstances.